# Matlab: visualize struct as a tree

Tags: matlab, visualization

I have implemented a binary tree in Matlab using "struct" to create nodes. Every node has some attributes and a left and a right child.

Is there a simple way to visualize this as a tree without having to draw lines etc.? (like view command for classregtree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will `treeplot` do the trick?

http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/treeplot.html

-Rob

Comment: Thanks. There is the treelayout function as well to help label the nodes.